# ‘Would not have’ and ‘did not’

Tags: modal-verbs

This is a quote from ‘The Wind in the Willows’:

> ‘Well, well, it can’t be helped,’ said the Rat, after pondering. ‘We must make a start, and take our chance, I suppose. The worst of it is, I don’t exactly know where we are. And now this snow makes everything look so very different.’ It did indeed. The Mole **would not have known** that it was the same wood. However, they set out bravely, and took the line that seemed most promising, holding on to each other and …

(1)Is ‘would not have known’ epistemic or non-epistemic?

(2)If I say ‘the Mole **did not know**’, what difference does it make?

Comment: The Mole _did_ know that it was the same wood, since they were still in it; it was only its appearance that was changed by the snow. The sense is 'if he had suddenly been shown a representation of the snow-covered wood, he would not have recognised it '.

Comment: I didn't make this an answer because I don't know what you mean by 'is it epistemic?'

Answer (score 2):

Mole and Rat were in the wood both before and after the snowfall, so they *did* know it was the same place. The meaning is that their surroundings looked so different covered in snow that Mole would not have recognised the scene if he had suddenly found himself there.

Answer (score 0):

'Would' has many uses, one of which is as a modal verb of probability *to refer to what is very likely*.

When speaking about what somebody else does or does not know it is not always possible to be certain. If you know without doubt that they "did not know" then you can say that, but if you are making an assumption, even one supported with evidence, it is perhaps better to say they "wouldn't have known".

Comment: But surely the author of a story can be assumed to know for certain what one of their characters knows!

Comment: @KateBunting Do you not understand the difference between the author and the narrator?

Comment: As far as I remember, _The Wind in the Willows_ is narrated in the authorial voice.

Comment: @KateBunting As far as I remember, *The Wind in the Willows* is about anthropomorphised animals that live in stately homes and drive cars. Surely you're not suggesting that the author was among them? Even so, the authorial voice is still a narrator, and can be unreliable.

Comment: _One_ (Toad) lives in a stately home; Mole and Rat live underground. What I mean is that Kenneth Grahame invented the characters and the story about them, so he 'knew' what his characters were thinking at any given moment!

Comment: @KateBunting You sound like you still don't get the difference. As an author, he knows the end from the beginning. But the narrator may tell the story as it unfolds. An author doesn't usually name themselves as the narrator. The narrator, while nameless, has a character or 'voice' of their own. Unless the narrative voice is meant to be omniscient and omnipresent then they cannot possibly know everything. They are presumed to know the story as it has been either seen, or related to them. There can be things unknown or presumed.

Comment: Yes, I know all that. WitW is not narrated through the eyes of a particular character, but through the author's omniscient voice.

Comment: @KateBunting You've gone from "as far as I remember" to being quite certain about how much the narrator of this book knows. The kind of narrator you're describing is usually defined as *all seeing* rather than *all knowing*. And you can't see what someone knows. The very quote the OP is asking about casts doubt on what you think about this narrator anyway. An omniscient narrator could be more dogmatic, a quality I'm sure you're familiar with.